# Install amdgpu drivers on Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, dpkg, amd-graphics, tar

Salutations All,

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS, and I have made it completely through the process of installing the AMDgpu drivers; yet at the end of the process when I run a package query, it finds no matching package.

Here are the exact steps I have taken:

sudo -s

wget --referer http://support.amd.com \ > https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz

tar xvf amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261.tar.xz

cd /amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261

./amdgpu-pro-install --compute

Each step of the process gives no indication that something has gone wrong. The installation just won't take:

dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
No such file or directory amdgpu-pro

Any insight as to why this might be the case would be very welcome. Thanks

Comment: `dpkg` and `apt` work from a database; any apps/modules installed by your outside of those tools won't appear in their database; so there is no problem.  (i wouldn't bother with vid-drivers for a server anyway)

Comment: @guiverc The amdgpu-pro install will install debian packages, so your comment is not correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMDGPU Pro package contains multiple debian packages which are installed by the installer. You would need to do `dpkg -l|grep amdgpu-pro` to get a more accurate listing.

Comment: As instructed, I ran dpkg -l|grep amdgpu-pro and it does in fact list the drivers. That said, I have a follow-up question. Why is it when I plug my AMDGPU's in via powered riser after installation and reboot I get a cascade of unending PCI-E errors?

Comment: That i cannot tell you. It's a separate question, and perhaps a bug somewhere, even possibly with the riser card. Not something that could be solved via comments on this question here.

Comment: It appears that it is a kernel module and not an application package. Suppose it's simply not loaded. How do I correct this?

Comment: Well, AMDGPU Pro is a lot of things. Mostly it is newer versions of the open source side of the driver (the kernel module, mesa, etc…), and a few proprietary bits for Vulkan/GL/CL. The `lsmod` command will show you the currently loaded modules. Simply loading the module won't help if the kernel can't identify the module should be loaded, though.  The errors you claim to get would suggest a deeper problem. Again, not something that can really be solved in comments here.